# Application linked with static mylib.a, but exe is looking for mylib.dll

Tags: qt, mingw, qt5

i created a static library mylib with Qt 5.5 in linux and link to it in my qt app and it all works

part of mylib create .pro file

```
TARGET  = mylib
TEMPLATE = lib

CONFIG  += staticlib
```

now, running the same with qt5.5 mingw32 in win7 appears to compile and link mylib without errors, but crashes myapp since it's looking for mylib.dll ...
why did the link process not link the static mylib.a to it

part of myapp link file

```
linux {
INCLUDEPATH +=   ../build-mylib-Desktop-Debug
LIBS        += -L../build-mylib-Desktop-Debug -lmylib
}
win32 {
INCLUDEPATH +=   ../build-mylib-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/debug
LIBS        += -L../build-mylib-Desktop_Qt_5_5_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/debug -lmylib
}
```

i don't understand why the same pro files work in linux, but in win7 with mingw32 it appears that the app linking with mylib.a doesn't happen, even no error and the mylib.a exists.

Comment: Did you entirely remove your build directory? Otherwise there is a chance that the linker finds some old shared lib when you compile your application.

Comment: I don't see enough info here, to have even the faintest clue as to how you built mylib.a, but if that's what it's really called, `-lmylib` will not find it, because it will cause the linker to search for `libmylib.dll.a`, `libmylib.a`, and then `mylib.dll`, in this order. Do you have any of those, in the linker search path?

Comment: thanks guys ... i always delete the dirs and pro.user files and open it fresh again if any changes seem suspicious ... i did it now one more time, the delete as described and this time it worked, maybe i missed a delete dir in my try before ...
i have the same issue with 3 different qt apps, one for usb-hid comm, one for normal serial and one for ble ... what i have tried now was the normal serial ... i will continue testing the other 2 and if i run into problems, i will post it

Answer (score 0):

deleting the debug / release build directories and as a safety measure also deleting the xxx.pro.user files to force a new project setup made it work

maybe it was not necessary to delete the xxx.pro.user files

i had a second issue with running the mylib.a within an usb-hid app using mingw32-libusb-1.0 binaries and hidapi source

mylib contained my own binary-type pkg type protocol code

i had the source of the hidapi code

i was able to get the hidapi source bundled together with the mylib code and compiled it into mylib.a

the app now had to link with mylib.a and the binaries of the mingw32-usblib-1.0 which all worked

trying to bundle the mingw32-usblib-1.0 with hidapi source and mylib code during the mylib.a creation process and later linking the app with the containing all libs now mylib.a worked in linux, but failed in win7

create library : hidapi source + mylib code -> mylib.a
create app : app code + mylib.a + mingw32-usblib-1.0 ... worked on linux and win7

create library : hidapi source + mylib code + mingw32-usblib-1.0 -> mylib.a
create app : app code + mylib.a ... worked on linux and failed on win7